# execute events javascript on cross domain using react js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

How can I execute event on external website using reactJS or angularJS.

This is what I'm trying to do.

```
var w = window.open('https://www.youtube.com/');
var x= w.console.log(performance.timing.responseEnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the use of react or angular, for execute instructions from one site to another you can use the parent-child messaging via iframe. Here more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

However, for realize this communication, the iframed page and the parent must allow this mechanism.

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Thank's for your reply. But it doesn't work.
Can you provide me some example on how to implement window.postMessage with youtube.com as described above.

Comment: window.postMessage works only if both parent and child pages allow this communication. I'm pretty sure that with youtube this solution won't work.